# Lack of VM_KEYPRESS in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

From http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html:

> **keydown**
>   Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keypress**
>   Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keyup**
>   Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

C# API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468861(v=vs.85).aspx

[KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**My question:** Why doesn't the keypress hex code exist in the C# API?

Comment: Probably because for the most part there is practically no difference between a key press and `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is handled in the message of keydown. The documentation of KEYDOWN states about the first 16 bits:

> The repeat count for the current message. The value is the number of times the keystroke is autorepeated **as a result of the user holding down the key**. If the keystroke is held long enough, multiple messages are sent. However, the repeat count is not cumulative.

So if the first 16 bits is bigger then 0, that is your flag for `KEYPRESS`.

The exact reason why it isn't a seperated flag is unknown to me.

Comment: So in other words I need to send multiple KEYDOWNs in order to simulate a keypress?

Comment: I never tried it but the documentation does seem to suggest it. You also might want to check the 30th byte which holds the previous key state.. But that again would suggest multuple KEYDOWNs...

Comment: I think you mean *bits*?

Comment: You're right I misread that, but I can't edit my comment because it is more than 4 minutes ago. But indeed the 30th bit in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the keypress hex code exist

I think you are talking about Windows messages.  It does exist, it just isn't named anything close to "keypress".  It is the [WM_CHAR message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It generates the KeyPress event in a C# app.  A better matching name in Store apps, the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event.

Giving some background, this message is generated by the TranslateMessage() winapi function.  A function you call in a message loop.  It takes a WM_KEYDOWN message and synthesizes WM_CHAR messages from it.  There can be anywhere from 0 to several.  The function that does this translation is also exposed, it is [ToUnicodeEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note how it needs to virtual key code, the scan code, the current keyboard state and the active keyboard layout to get its job done.  The keyboard state is important so you get different characters when you hold the Shift key down.  The keyboard layout is how Windows can support different languages and having the same virtual key codes produce entirely different typing characters.

Never assume you can synthesize typing characters from KeyDown events yourself, you can't get it accurate.  Dead keys on some keyboard layouts are impossible to handle correctly, you cannot obtain the keyboard state for another process.